# How to set a button on Vue to appear once all API calls have finished retrieving data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I set my report button to appear once all the data is loaded from the most recent click of my budget button? I have a button once clicked gets budgets and displays them on a grid in Vue using a Kendo Grid. To load the data faster it will load the grid with the initial data before calling another API to get two more columns of data for the grid. These second round of calls can take a while so they are set to go 10 at a time in a for loop. What is the easiest way to display this button once the data is done loading?

I posted my current method to get my budgets and the computed I am setting the report button to appear when true. Some current issues I am facing are with multiple clicks to the get budgets button, even if I set the estimateAmounts object array to empty at the beginning of the getBudgets method, the loop from the previous call may still be iterating and could still add to the estimateAmounts offsetting it from being able to == the data object in my computing. Any ideas or direction on the best way to go with this one? Please let me know if you have any questions or need any more information.

```
    data() {
                return {
                    budgets: [],
                    estimateAmounts: {},
                }
           },
methods: {
    async getBudgets() {

                this.isLoading = true;
                this.budgets = []
                this.estimateAmounts = {}
                const data = await api.budget.getBudgetReport({ 
                  accountIds: this.accountIds.map(a => a.accountId),
                  salesRepIds: this.selectedSalesReps.map(sr => sr.userId),
                  startDate: this.startDate, 
                  endDate: this.endDate 
                })
                this.budgets = data.map(d => { return { ...d, startDate: new Date(d.startDate) } })
                this.isLoading = false;

                // group calculations in 10's to run concurrently and return results faster
                let idSets = chunk(data.map(d => d.budgetId), 10)
                for (const ids of idSets)
                    api.budget.calculateTotalsForBudgets(ids, this.user.userId)
                        .then(res => this.estimateAmounts = { ...this.estimateAmounts, ...res })
            },
    },

    computed: {
        setButtons() {
                        return Object.keys(this.estimateAmounts).length == this.budgets.length && this.budgets.length > 0
                    },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly you just want to wait for all your parallel api calls to complete to then show a button somewhere in the template, right? If that's the case, it can be achieved with `await Promise.all` without any computed property. Something like:

```
this.showButton = true;
await Promise.all(
    idSets.map(async (ids) => {
        await api.budget.calculateTotalsForBudgets(ids, this.user.userId);
    })
);
this.showButton = false;
```

I've added this new `showButton` state as an example, but maybe you could even use your existing `isLoading` state -- just move it below.

Comment: The problem with awaiting the function is it doesn't allow me to load them 10 at a time and forces me to wait for all of the calls to be loaded at once. We would like to be able to load 10 at a time on the front end for our grid

Comment: So let me see if I understood it. You want:
(1) the api calls to run in parallel to return results faster.
(2) the button to show up only after all parallel api requests are finished.
(3) whenever an API call answers back, you that data to be added to `this.estimateAmounts`, without having to wait for the other parallel calls.

Is that correct?